# Creating a simple binary to decimal table in javascript - homework

Tags: javascript, function, binary, decimal

I am trying to create a simple binary to decimal table in javascript using logical functions. The output should look like this:

Binary      | Decimal
CCCC
3  2  1  0 | 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
0  0  0  0  | 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0  0  0  1  | 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0  0  1  0  | 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0  0  1  1  | 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0  1  0  0  | 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0  1  0  1  | 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0  1  1  0  | 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0  1  1  1  | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
1  0  0  0  | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
1  0  0  1  | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1

This is what I have so far, not sure why it is not working - i guess there is something wrong with the logical functions, any help would be much appreciated :)

```
<script language="JavaScript">

var C3 = new Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1);
var C2 = new Array(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0);
var C1 = new Array(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0);
var C0 = new Array(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1);

var D0,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9;

// printing out the header of the table 
document.write(" C3 C2 C1 C0| 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 <BR>");


for (var i = 0; i <= 9; i++ ) 
{
// calculating values according to logical equations
D0 = AND(NOT(C3[i]),NOT(C2[i]),NOT(C1[i]),NOT(C0[i]));
D1 = AND(NOT(C3[i]),NOT(C2[i]),NOT(C1[i]),C0[i]);
D2 = AND(NOT(C3[i]),NOT(C2[i]),C1[i],NOT(C0[i]));
D3 = AND(NOT(C3[i]),NOT(C2[i]),C1[i],C0[i]);
D4 = AND(NOT(C3[i]),C2[i],NOT(C1[i]),NOT(C0[i]));
D5 = AND((NOT(C3[i]),C2[i],NOT(C1[i]),C0[i]); 
D6 = AND(NOT(C3[i]),C2[i],C1[i],NOT(C0[i]));
D7 = AND(NOT(C3[i]),C2[i],C1[i],C0[i]);
D8 = AND(C3[i],NOT(C2[i]),NOT(C1[i]),NOT(C0[i]));
D9 = AND(C3[i],NOT(C2[i]),NOT(C1[i]),C0[i]);

// printing the outputs
document.write(C3[i] + " " + C2[i] + " " C1[i] + " " + C0[i] +  " | " + D0 + " " +
D1   + " " + D2 + " " + D3 + " " + D4 + " " + D5 + " " + D6 + " " + D7 + " " + D8 
+ " + D9 + "<BR>");
}

// defining function NOT
function NOT(inp) {
var out = 1 & (!inp);
return out;
}

//  defining function AND
function AND(in1,in2,in3,in4)
{
var out = in1 && in2 && in3 && in4;
return out
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining the `AND` and `NOT` functions before you run your code.  Cut them and paste them before you're running the for loop, and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks, this together with deleting a typo in D5 made it :)

Comment: @Vero, if my answer solved your question, would you mind accepting it?  Thank you.  :D